# "Invalid Field Name" Exception when using Provisioning

Tags: content-type, provisioning-providers

I wanted to create a site template package. Instead of going with a custom site definition, I planned to go with the recommended "Provisioning Provider" technique. The solution was going just fine. created all my features and modules, in the provisioning class I added them to my site one by one and it was working. One I added the module responsible for provisioning the content types, the package stopped working and started receiving the error "Invalid field name {GUID}",  whenever I try to create a site collection, where the {GUID} is the GUID of the first field in the content type fields XML tags.

My content types XML is fairly simple:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!--############################# Start Research Publication Site Columns & Content Type ###############################-->
    <Field  Type="Text" DisplayName="Publication Keywords" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Research Publication Columns" ID="{4aa3e7aa-a406-4c5e-b5fe-e6be1736f2ca}"   Name="PublicationKeywords" />
    <Field  Type="HTML" DisplayName="Abstract" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml" Required="TRUE" Group="Research Publication Columns" ID="{fb736a77-13e4-41bc-b760-76b2a56e360e}"   Name="Abstract" />
    <Field  Type="Text" DisplayName="Year" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Research Publication Columns" ID="{0dc658e0-6ebb-47f2-b99c-fd2ee5c76887}"   Name="Year" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" />
    <Field  Type="Text" DisplayName="ISSN" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Research Publication Columns" ID="{27823082-9ffd-4dc5-8a0f-d7096e89ac8b}"   Name="ISSN" />
    <Field  Type="URL"  DisplayName="Website Link" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="Hyperlink" Group="Research Publication Columns" ID="{c9c1c58c-ae91-4c92-b403-c7aacee5bdb1}"   Name="WebsiteLink"  />
    <Field  Type="URL"  DisplayName="Document Link" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="Hyperlink" Group="Research Publication Columns" ID="{5e7a4c4e-e18f-4b7b-9dd1-4d96ee1f8a13}"   Name="DocumentLink" />
    <!-- Research Publication Content Type -->
    <ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D05" Group="Research Content Types" Name="Research Publication" Description="Represents research publications content type." Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{4aa3e7aa-a406-4c5e-b5fe-e6be1736f2ca}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{fb736a77-13e4-41bc-b760-76b2a56e360e}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{0dc658e0-6ebb-47f2-b99c-fd2ee5c76887}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{27823082-9ffd-4dc5-8a0f-d7096e89ac8b}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{c9c1c58c-ae91-4c92-b403-c7aacee5bdb1}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{5e7a4c4e-e18f-4b7b-9dd1-4d96ee1f8a13}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
    <!--############################# End Research Publication Site Columns & Content Type ###############################-->


    <!--############################# Start Research Events Site Columns & Content Type ###############################-->
    <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Event Title" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="Research Event Columns" ID="{63da83d2-2e0a-4556-8136-8b6a4acdb1bc}" SourceID="{ab60d3a0-898d-46c5-a8c3-797a3c2f6b11}" StaticName="EventTitle" Name="EventTitle" Version="1" Hidden="FALSE" Customization="" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
    <Field Type="HTML" DisplayName="Event Brief Description" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml" Required="TRUE" Group="Research Event Columns" ID="{4f4fe0d4-a72c-4afe-8585-d7a76c4f15b5}" SourceID="{ab60d3a0-898d-46c5-a8c3-797a3c2f6b11}" StaticName="EventBriefDescription" Name="EventBriefDescription" Description="This Brief Description will show only in the events listing page (landing page)" Version="2" Hidden="FALSE" Customization="" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
    <Field Type="HTML" DisplayName="Event Details" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml" Required="FALSE" Group="Research Event Columns" ID="{bfe967b8-0ba1-4757-8c5d-d6652719865c}" SourceID="{ab60d3a0-898d-46c5-a8c3-797a3c2f6b11}" StaticName="EventDetails" Name="EventDetails" Customization="" />
    <Field Type="Image" DisplayName="Event Thumbnail" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml" Description="This image will show only in the events listing page (landing page)" Required="TRUE" Group="Research Event Columns" ID="{825d2283-78f4-4878-b4c5-318cdc15f949}" SourceID="{ab60d3a0-898d-46c5-a8c3-797a3c2f6b11}" StaticName="EventThumbnail" Name="EventThumbnail" Version="1" Hidden="FALSE" Customization="" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
    <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Event Start Date" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Group="Research Event Columns" ID="{71800b8f-3d7c-4356-bb1a-dee72d1b3c78}" SourceID="{ab60d3a0-898d-46c5-a8c3-797a3c2f6b11}" StaticName="EventStartDate" Name="EventStartDate" Hidden="FALSE" Customization="" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />
    <Field Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Event End Date" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateTime" Group="Research Event Columns" ID="{5ff912dd-19c8-43c1-ba50-5a4734740ab7}" SourceID="{ab60d3a0-898d-46c5-a8c3-797a3c2f6b11}" StaticName="EventEndDate" Name="EventEndDate" Hidden="FALSE" Customization="" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node="" />

    <ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D01" Name="Research Events" Group="Research Content Types" Version="11">
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{63da83d2-2e0a-4556-8136-8b6a4acdb1bc}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{4f4fe0d4-a72c-4afe-8585-d7a76c4f15b5}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{bfe967b8-0ba1-4757-8c5d-d6652719865c}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{825d2283-78f4-4878-b4c5-318cdc15f949}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{71800b8f-3d7c-4356-bb1a-dee72d1b3c78}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{5ff912dd-19c8-43c1-ba50-5a4734740ab7}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>
    <!--############################# End Research Events Site Columns & Content Type ###############################-->
</Elements>
```

and my provisioning class looks like this:

```
public override void Provision(SPWebProvisioningProperties props)
        {
            // apply template using a configuration for Blank Publishing site
            props.Web.ApplyWebTemplate("BLANKINTERNET#0");

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(props.Web.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb site = siteCollection.OpenWeb(props.Web.ID))
                    {

                        siteCollection.Features.Add(new Guid("a6bce603-1626-41ff-a107-3561f379be6d"));

                        site.Title = "Research Center Site Title";
                        site.Description = "This site was created on " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                        site.Update();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

is there any known issue regarding creating content types using the provisioning providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a "Name" property, "DisplayName", etc on the fieldref in addition to just the GUID. Here is a link to the FieldRef element. Check the required fields.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx

Comment: It Worked. after adding the name and the display name attributes. Strange though because VS 2010 is not enforcing these attributes for the fieldRef element

Comment: Visual Studio's intellisense can be spotty both in terms of missing required elements, and identifying invalid elements. You can't really trust it.